# AWS SDK (C#) using TransferUtility to upload a directory with multiple search patterns

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The following code uploads all files in a single directory with the .jpg extension to a named Amazon S3 bucket.  The third argument in UploadDirectoryAsync() is a search pattern (string) that defines the files to match.  Is it possible to match more than one file type?

```
TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(accessKey, secretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APNortheast1);
                fileTransferUtility.UploadDirectoryAsync(folder, bucketName, "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

For example, something like:

```
"*.jpg|*.png|*.gif"
```

It doesn't appear to work with a regular expression, so I'm wondering if it can be done.  The official reference doesn't provide much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK for .NET passes the `searchPattern` of `UploadDirectoryAsync()` directly to [`Directory.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which doesn't seem to support patterns beyond simple wildcards.

Comment: Thanks.  Not the answer I was hoping for, but accurate and informative nonetheless.